# Should I use two profiles in GA for tracking android and ios apps

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

We have two native apps (Android & iOS). Both implement same functionality. We now want to add Google Analytics tracking to both apps. Is it better to use two separate profiles or have one profile with filters set up for both operating systems? 
It would be great to be able to see overall traffic both apps generate, but most important is to be able to check performance per app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multpile tracker ids in the latest version of the [Google Analytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced#multiple-trackers) so you can have a combined tracker for iOS and android as well as a separate tracker for each app.

Answer (score 3):

#### Best Practices for Mobile App Analytics set up

> **Track different platforms of an app in the same property.**
> If you’ve developed the same app for different platforms (i.e., MyApp for Android and MyApp for iOS), track them in the same property. You can then set up new views to organize and compare the performances in your Google Analytics reports. If your iOS and Android apps differ greatly in performance or usage, you might want to track each platform in separate properties.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en

Comment: These best practices have changed - see new answer by @szakal.

Answer (score 2):

A recommandation probably has changed and now you can find:

**Track different platforms of an app in different properties.**

> If you’ve developed the same app for different platforms (i.e., MyApp for Android and MyApp for iOS), track them in different properties. If you want to see the data together, creating an account with AdMob allows you to get a view of all of your data in one place with a rollup property. You can then set up new views to organize and compare the performances in your Google Analytics reports.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en

Comment: How annoying that they've changed this.  Too late to go back and re-do all our apps & tracking.